# Android Correct Screen Density

Tags: android, android-screen

I've [come across](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android) with this table showing what Android uses as baseline for screen density:
[image]

Here i understand that if my `mdpi` image is 100px, then i have to use 150px(1.5 factor) for `hdpi`.

**Question 1:** Does `mdpi` targets screen densities between `120dpi` screen and `160dpi` screen? Because my phone has `432dpi`(or `ppi`) and it uses `xxhdpi`, so i thought `xxhdpi` targets screen densities between `320dpi` and `480dpi`, right?

But here i've [came across](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android) with different table, showing example:
[image]

**Question 2:** According to assumption above, `xhdpi` should target between `240dpi-320dpi`, but in second table `336dpi` is also considered as `xhdpi`, why? And what happens if user has screen density > `480dpi` and i don't have `xxxhdpi` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android picks the right density bucket for a given DPI value based on the bucket which has the least difference in DPI value.This can easily be seen in de following image:

[image: DPI buckets]

Quote:

> Figure 1. Illustration of how Android roughly maps actual sizes and densities to generalized sizes and densities (figures are not exact).

Source: [http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2g3Y.jpg)

**Question 1:**
Mdpi targets roughly anything between 140 DPI and 180 DPI.

**Question 2:** 336 DPI is considered xhdpi because the xhdpi bucket is the closest one (in DPI value: 6). The difference to the hdpi bucket is 96 and the difference to the xxhdpi bucket is 144.

When a density folder is missing Android picks the best alternative folder and if needed applies scaling to the resources to match the target density.